# regarding VRT column of top command's output on linux

Tags: linux, top-command

In the man pages of top command, it is given that VRT column shows memory consumption in kb(kilo bits). When i am running my application in linux, memory consumed is shown as 157m. Does this 157m mean 157 mega bytes or 157 mega bits? Any clarifiction is appreciated.

Comment: Anyone posting a reply containing 'mibi' should be auto-banned for a day :P

Comment: you should browse through your previously asked questions (click on your username and find them) and **ACCEPT** answers if they are correct. Click on the green 'V'-sign left of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's in MegaBytes. Put the output from your `top` next to the output from `ps aux`.

```
> ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0    780    72 ?        S    Jun26   0:09 init [3]
mysql    28670  2.1 42.1 2733944 1708028 ?     Sl   Sep24 1910:21 /usr/sbin/mysqld 

>top
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
28670 mysql     15   0 2667m 1.6g 4164 S  104 42.2   1910:37 mysqld
```